# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java. I made a project that is depended on a JOGL project.

My code runs perfectly fine in eclipse.

But if I export it into a .jar file and double click on it, nothing shows up.

When I run the .jar in the CMD, it shows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\Frank\natives\windows-amd64\gluegen-rt.dll

What could be wrong? How should I fix this?

Please help thanks!!

P.S. I have tried all 3 options in eclipse while exporting (Extract required libraries into generated JAR etc...)

Comment: Did you try providing library path using parameter -Djava.library.path=YOUR_LIB_PATH while running the program?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! I'm noob and I don't know how to do that.. A little more details please?